# Should we add php-fpm for each Virtual Host or in Global Configuration?

Tags: nginx

This is my configuration for my Virtual Host. I am not sure, but is this the ideal way of defining things ?

For every domain / sub-domain, i'm adding a location ~/.php directive. Should i add it in the global nginx.conf itself instead of specifying individually for each domain i add ?

Sample Configuration :-

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;

location / {
   root /var/www/example.com;
   index index.php;

}


location ~ \.php$ {
   root /var/www/example.com/;
   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
   fastcgi_index index.php;
  #fastcgi_read_timeout 30000;
  #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
  include fastcgi_params;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.example.net;

location / {
  root /var/www/example.net/;
  index index.php;

}


location ~ \.php$ {
  root /var/www/example.net/;
  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  # fastcgi_read_timeout 30000;
  # fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
  include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: If you read documentation you'll see that there is no "global" location

Comment: oh, so is this the right way that i've been doing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put `location` outside of `server` block. The best you could do is to put repeated part into file and `include` that file.

Also, usually you SHOUD NOT declare `root` directive inside every `location`, declare it once inside `server`.

And, BTW, `index` directive could be outside of `server` block, in that case it affects all `server` blocks that do not have theirs own `index` directive.

So here is config that does exactly the save as yours, but with less repetitions.

```
index index.php;

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  root /var/www/example.com;

  include location-php;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.net;
  root /var/www/example.net;

  include location-php;
}
```

and `location-php` file:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
  include fastcgi_params;
}
```